# Linux - Qmake Compiling Error - 'vorbisfile not found' although installed

Tags: linux, qt, compiler-errors, qmake

I try to compile Goldendict on Debian. I have installed all the necessary dependencies, including `libvorbis-dev`, as listed in the 'README.md' file. However, I'm immediately running into the following error message when executing `qmake` or `qmake-qt4`.

```
JohnDoe@debian:~/goldendict$ qmake
Project MESSAGE: Install Prefix is: /usr/local
sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
Project ERROR: Package vorbisfile not found
JohnDoe@debian:~/goldendict$
```

I have tried to install it without the audio player support, but it's not working either.

```
JohnDoe@debian:~/goldendict$ sudo qmake "DISABLE_INTERNAL_PLAYER=1"
Project MESSAGE: Install Prefix is: /usr/local
sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
Project ERROR: Package vorbisfile not found
JohnDoe@debian:~/goldendict$
```

I have Qt version 4.8.6 installed.

Here are the instructions on 'how-to install Goldendict', which I have followed: https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict/blob/master/README.md

How can I get this work? Any help is welcome.

PS: Here's the proof that the vorbis package is installed.

PROOF from dpkg:

```
JohnDoe@debian:~$ dpkg -s libvorbis-dev
Package: libvorbis-dev
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 1715
Maintainer: Debian Xiph.org Maintainers <pkg-xiph-maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: same
Source: libvorbis
Version: 1.3.4-2
Depends: libogg-dev, libvorbis0a (= 1.3.4-2), libvorbisenc2 (= 1.3.4-2), libvorbisfile3 (= 1.3.4-2)
```

PROOF from apt-get:

```
JohnDoe@debian:~/goldendict$ sudo apt-get install libvorbis-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libvorbis-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
JohnDoe@debian:~/goldendict$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not on Debian, but on Mac it was a problem. The workaround is, you can change your `.pro` file for Qt projects, so that it does not look for `pkg-config`, by adding the following line:

```
QT_CONFIG -= no-pkg-config
```

Another guess would be that your path is not set properly. I would try adding the `pkg-config` path to the environment variable:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/<path_to_pkg-config>/pkgconfig
```

Comment: @like444 - I will check this later and definitely report back to you. Good hint!!

Comment: Great, thanks for the hint with the path! I have run into another issue during compiling, which would be another question though.